# Why doesn't partial specialization need forward declaration?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Today I write the code below with a mistake:

```
template<int V>
typename std::enable_if<(V > 0)>::type
Test() {
  Test<V - 1>();
}

template<int V>
typename std::enable_if<(V == 0)>::type
Test() {
  std::cout << "0" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  Test<1>();
}
```

The compiler errored my that `no matching function for call to ‘Test<(1 - 1)>()’`, I checked and found that I should put the `std::enable_if<(V == 0)>::type` version first, or , I use forward declaration like this:

```
// forward declaration
template<int V>
typename std::enable_if<(V == 0)>::type
Test();

template<int V>
typename std::enable_if<(V > 0)>::type
Test() {
  Test<V - 1>();
}

template<int V>
typename std::enable_if<(V == 0)>::type
Test() {
  std::cout << "0" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  Test<1>();
}
```

The I noticed that when I write code using partial specialization, I never met this problem before, for example:

```
template <int V, typename = void>
struct Foo {
  static void Test() {
    std::cout << V << std::endl;
    Foo<V - 1>::Test();
  }
};

template <int V>
struct Foo <V, typename std::enable_if<V == 0>::type> {
  static void Test() {
    std::cout << "0" << std::endl;
  }
};


int main() {
 Foo<1>::Test();
}
```

this code works find and I didn't use forward declaration, so here's my question:

Why the function version cannot "see" functions declarations after itself, while the struct version knows? Did SFINAE happened in the function version's compilation?

P.S. Here's the error message using clang, which seems more specific:

```
/home/liu/source/untitled4/main.cpp:7:3: error: call to function 'Test' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
  Test<V - 1>();
```

And here's the error message I mentioned in my question using GCC:

```
/home/liu/source/untitled4/main.cpp:7:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘Test<(1 - 1)>()’
   Test<V - 1>();
```

And I don't have a Windows environment on my hand for now, I'll paste the error later if MSVC reports errors.

Comment: imho it would be nice if you include the complete error message in the question. I like to read the full message and to reproduce it I had to modify your code.

Comment: Which compiler is this? Until very recently, MSVC did not perform correct two-phase lookup as required by the standard. GCC is perfectly happy with it: https://godbolt.org/z/W9a1nP

Comment: The last fragment has a definition of the main template in front of the specialisation. A definition is a declaration. You don't need another (forward) one. Other fragments have no specialisations at all. They are normal function templates.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I got the feeling, but do you know where to find the detail lookup rules? Does this rules defined by standard(I just searched and found nothing)?

Comment: @RichardHodges gcc complains about this one: https://godbolt.org/z/7qnYPs (the first snippet)

Comment: @RichardHodges, you used the correct version in my code, remove the forward declaration will reproduce the issue using gcc.

Comment: Ah sorry - early in the morning for me. I’m not at my best :)

Comment: There is no such things as partial template function specialisation. You have overloaded function templates. What lookup rules do you  mean? Just do not access what was not declared. The first `Test` doesn't see the second `Test` because the second `Test` is declared below it, that's all. They are two completely different and independent function templates.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm, "They are two completely different and independent function templates" do your suggest that all partial specification templates are not totally independent, the compiler handles them all for lookup no matter what the partial specification declaration orders? If it is, that's the "lookup rules" I mean.

Comment: Only class templates can be partially specialised. Function templates can be only completely specialised. You do not even attempt to define a function template specialisation, partial or otherwise.  A specialisation of a function template `Test` **must** look like `template<> (return-type) Test<true>()`  I do not suggest that different specialisations of the same template are independent. I suggest that the templates **you** have defined are **not** specialisations, and that they are independent templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the comments have addressed the *problem*—that each **independent** function template must be declared before use—the *question* about the difference can be answered simply by quoting [temp.class.spec.general]/7:

> Partial specialization declarations themselves are not found by name lookup. Rather, when the primary template name is used, any previously-declared partial specializations of the primary template are also considered.  […]

As such, it is the specializations that are reachable from the **point of instantiation** that are available, and so mutual references may be made freely prior to any instantiation.  (This is akin to the rule for lookup for *dependent* function names.)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quote of the standard, but do you know why standard doesn't allow independent function template to do the same thing? I know template functions do not have partial specialization feature, but the "any previously-declared (partial) specializations of the primary template are also considered" seems not very hard to  applies to independent function template...

Comment: @psionic12: It’s simply that name lookup doesn’t look forwards, which makes it more predictable.  (Dependent ADL does look from the point of instantiation, but it’s supposed to be restricted to declarations relevant to the types involved.)